# How to add text input filter on Data Table for every column filter?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I work on an ANSP.net MVC app, and I face the issue that I can't add text input filter on top of every column to filter data related to every column with another, meaning I have data table have 3 columns `RequestNo` and `EmpId` and `EmpName`.

So I will add 3 input box filter for 3 column every column from `requestNo` and `EmpId` and `EmpName`.

So the shape will be:

```
RequestNo                 EmpId                     EmpName

input text box filter    input text box filter    input text box filter
```

every input text box will filter column related to it

How to do it using jQuery or JavaScript?

```
 <table id="dtbl" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="width:100%;padding-left:5px;padding-right:7px;">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">

                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequestNo)
                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmpID).ToString().Replace(":", "")
                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmpName).ToString().Replace(":", "")
                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">View Form</th>
              
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">

                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestNo)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpID)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpName)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.ActionLink("View Form", "Details", new { id = item.RequestNo })
                    </td>
                    
                  
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dtbl').DataTable({
                "scrollX": true,
                "pageLength": 10,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
             
                initComplete: function () {
                    // Remove export buttons
                    $('.buttons-excel, .buttons-pdf, .buttons-print, .buttons-csv, .buttons-copy').remove();
                }
            });
        });
```

updated post

I will show you desired result with red color as below

[image: filter issue]
​

what I try Add jQuery code below and it draw cells input for search

but You search for any thing not work when I try to search .

My question why search not working for any cell input please

meaning if employee name have `michel` and I write `michel` or part

from  word it will not work why ?

```
$('#dtbl thead th').each(function () {
                var title = $(this).text();
                if (title !== 'View Form' && title !== 'Print' && title !== 'Print Arabic') { // Exclude the 'View Form' column
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
                }
            });

            // Apply the search
            table.columns().every(function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
```

**Finally Issue Search still Exist but cell input for search Draw
so How to solve issue ?**

Comment: FYI, repeated style attributes throughout your markup are not good, and [Bootstrap provides border colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/content/tables/#table-borders) anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Add filter individually per every column for Data Table by apply filter for every column success

and solved my issue

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        

        new DataTable('#dtbl', {
            "dom": 'rtip',
            initComplete: function () {
                $('#dtbl tfoot tr').insertAfter($('#dtbl thead tr'))
                this.api()
                    .columns()
                    .every(function () {
                        let column = this;
                        let title = column.footer().textContent;

                         //Create input element
                        let input = document.createElement('input');
                        input.placeholder = title;
                        column.footer().replaceChildren(input);

                        //var input = $('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');

                        //// Append input element to the footer cell
                        //$(column.footer()).html(input);

                        // Event listener for user input
                        input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
                            if (column.search() !== this.value) {
                                column.search(input.value).draw();
                            }
                        });
                    });
            }
        });
  });
```